# Load assets from different path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this load url:

```
www.domain.com/library/assets/module1/table/js/data.min.js?v=10.1
```

My File is located at: `/assets/module1/table/js/data.min.js`

I tried this htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^/library/assets/(.*) /assets/$1
```

but it does not work. I got 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and testing I solved it by:

```
RewriteRule ^library/assets/(.*) /assets/$1  [NC,L]
```